# Printing integers from command line arguments in C

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, argv, argc

I'm running my program with some command line arguments. But when I enter 10, 10, 10 and print them out, it prints out 49, 49, 49. Here's my code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int seed = *argv[0];
    int arraySize = *argv[1];
    int maxSize = *argv[2];
```

Why is this happening??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `argv` is an array of pointer to strings. All command line arguments are passed as *strings* and the pointer to each of them is held by `argv[n]`, where the sequence for the argument is `n+1`.

For a hosted environment, quoting `C11`, chapter §5.1.2.2.1

> If the value of `argc` is greater than zero, the string pointed to by `argv[0]`
>   represents the *program name*; `argv[0][0]` shall be the null character if the
>   program name is not available from the host environment. If the value of `argc` is
>   greater than one, the strings pointed to by `argv[1]` through `argv[argc-1]`
>   represent the program parameters.

So, clearly, for an execution like

> ./123 10 10 10   //123 is the binary name

- `argv[0]` is not the first "command line argument passed to the program". It's `argv[1]`.
- `*argv[1]` does not return the `int` value you passed as the command-line argument.

  Basically, `*argv[1]` gives you the value of the first element of that *string* (i.e, a `char` value of `'1'`), most possibly in ASCII encoded value (which you platform uses), ansd according to the [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/) a `'1'` has the decimal va;lue of `49`, which you see.

Solution: You need to

- Check for the number of arguments (`argc`)
- Loop over each argument string `argv[1] ~ argv[n-1]` while `argc == n`
- Convert each of the input *string* to `int` (for this case, you can make use of [`strtol()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol))

Answer (score 1):

Dereferencing a string (`*argv[x]`) gives you a `char` (the value of the first character in the string), in this case the value is ASCII `'1'`: decimal 49

You can convert those strings (without dereferencing) using [strtol](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html)

```
int arraySize = (int)strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
```

Anyway `argv[0]` is the name of your program, are you sure that the program name starts with 1?